# Usar INSERT utilizando SELECT (Node.js e MySql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Preciso inserir alguns dados em uma tabela, utilizando o seguinte código:

```js
var query = `INSERT INTO uso (id_usuario, id_tempo) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE nome='Jose' LIMIT 1), (SELECT id FROM tempo WHERE timestamp=1505530800000 AND nome='dia_de_hoje' LIMIT 1));
INSERT INTO uso (id_usuario, id_tempo)VALUES ((SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE nome='Joao' LIMIT 1), (SELECT id FROM tempo WHERE timestamp=1505530800000 AND nome='dia_de_hoje' LIMIT 1))`

    connection.query(query, function(err, results) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(results);
    });
```

mas estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO uso (id_usuario, id_tempo) 
>       VALUES ((SELECT id FROM usuar' at line 3
>       at Query.Sequence._packetToError (

Quando faço essa consulta direto no servidor, o `insert` funciona normalmente.

Comment: Tente utilizar uma atribuição, por exemplo **SELECT id as id_usuario FROM usuario...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O caractere que você está utilizando não é um delimitador de `String` valido para o `JavaScript`. Fiz algumas modificações na `query` também para representá-la mais facilmente:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO uso(id_usuario, id_tempo)\r\n" +
            "SELECT u.id,\r\n" +
            "       (SELECT id\r\n" +
            "          FROM tempo\r\n" +
            "         WHERE timestamp = 1505530800000\r\n" +
            "           AND nome = 'dia_de_hoje'\r\n" +
            "         LIMIT 1)\r\n" +
            "  FROM usuario\r\n" +
            " WHERE nome IN ('Joao', 'Jose')";

connection.query(query, function(err, results) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score -4):

basta usar

```
while c > 1 
select id from tempo;

SET c = c - 1;

end while;
```